# ArgumentException: must be reducible node

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.0

I am creating a ASP.NET Core Web API for my company to manage customers and contracts (more features will be added later). I was following this awesome guide (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-awesome-guide-on-how-to-build-restful-apis-with-asp-net-core-87b818123e28/).

The first table ("Customer") queries perfectly with EF Core 3. However, when I try to query the the other table ("Contract") I get the `ArgumentException: must be reducible node`-exception. (Note: each "Customer" can have many "Contract"s and each "Contract" is linked to one and only one "Customer".)

I have Googled this issue and most solutions suggest upgrading EF Core to a higher version. However, I am already running EF Core v3 (preview 7), which is the latest version right now. Is this a bug in EF Core, or am I doing something wrong?

The code I use:

I have 2 classes, 1 `Customer` class:

```cs
public class Customer
{
    // Properties
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Segment { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public bool SendReminders { get; set; } = true;
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    // Foreign Properties
    public IList<Contract> Contracts { get; set; } = new List<Contract>();

    // Logging Properties
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And a `Contract` class:

```cs
public class Contract
{
    // Properties
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    // Foreign Properties
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    //Logging Properties
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

The I override the `OnModelCreating` method of the `DBContext`:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer");
    builder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
    builder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.ID).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    builder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
    builder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.Type).HasMaxLength(25);
    builder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.Segment).HasMaxLength(25);
    builder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.ContactPerson).HasMaxLength(50);
    builder.Entity<Customer>().HasMany(x => x.Contracts).WithOne(y => y.Customer).HasForeignKey(y => y.CustomerID);

    builder.Entity<Customer>().HasData(
        new Customer { ID = 100, Name = "Cust1" }, // ID set manually due to in-memory provider
        new Customer { ID = 101, Name = "Cust2" }
    );

    builder.Entity<Contract>().ToTable("Contract");
    builder.Entity<Contract>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
    builder.Entity<Contract>().Property(x => x.ID).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    builder.Entity<Contract>().Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

    builder.Entity<Contract>().HasData(
        new Contract { ID = 100, Name = "DLA", CustomerID = 100, Notes = "Cust1 contract" },
        new Contract { ID = 101, Name = "DLA", CustomerID = 101, Notes = "Cust2 contract" }
    );
}
```

And when I query the table "Contract" to get all contracts, this method is called:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Contract>> ListAsync()
{
    return await _context.Contracts.Include(c => c.Customer).ToListAsync();
    //return await _context.Contracts.ToListAsync();
}
```

The commented line shows all contracts, but does not join the "Contract" table with the "Customer" table. So I use the `Include` method of LINQ for that. However, that line of code throws the `ArgumentException: must be reducible node`-exception.

I followed the guide strictly (but of course changed the name to my needs). Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a bug in EF Core 3?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: EF Core 3.0 is still in *preview*, thus is expected to have issues like this (not caused by your code). Preview versions are not supposed to be used in production code. Use the latest *release*  (currently [2.2.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/2.2.6)).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I found out, however, that when I switch from an in-memory database to a SQL database, everything just works fine. The idea was to use a SQL server anyway. The in-memory database was only temporarily used for testing purposes.